# Convert an enum to a list in Python

Tags: python, enums, assert

I have an enum that I define like this:

```
def make_enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

an_enum = make_enum(first=1, second=2)
```

At some later point I would like to check, if a value that I took as a parameter in a funciton is part of `an_enum`. Usually i would do it like this

`assert 1 in to_list(an_enum)`

How can I convert the enum object `an_enum` to a list? If that is not possible, how can I check if a value "is part of the enum"?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Already thought about that. I think you can only use that, if you are working with the class of the enum. Since I do not define a class, that does not seem to be possible

Comment: Try `type(an_enum)` to get the class?

Comment: Beginning in Python 3.4 there is an actual `Enum` type that supports `list(an_enum)` plus much more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I convert the enum object an_enum to a list?

```
>>> [name for name in dir(an_enum) if not name.startswith('_')]
['first', 'second']
```

> How can I check if a value "is part of the enum"?

```
>>> getattr(an_enum, 'first')
1
>>> getattr(an_enum, '1')
Traceback [...] 
AttributeError: type object 'Enum' has no attribute '1'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OP is asking for enum value membership check, not name check

Comment: So the above version would give you al the attributes. But this really helped, because you can simply change that to `[getattr(an_enum, name) for name in dir(an_enum) if not name.startswith('_')]` and you will get what I need `[1, 2]`

Comment: [element.name for element in an_enum] is more consise

Answer (score 13):

Python's Enum object has build-in `enumerable.name` and `enumerable.value` attributes for each member of an Enum.

```
an_enum = Enum('AnEnum', {'first': 1, 'second': 2})


[el.value for el in an_enum]
# returns: [1, 2]

[el.name for el in an_enum]
# returns: ['first', 'second']
```

*Sidenode: Be careful with `assert`. If someone runs your script with `python -O` asserts will never fail.*

To check if a value is part of an enum:

```
if 1 in [el.value for el in an_enum]:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're defining enums like you do, there's supported functional way to do this:

```
en_enum = Enum('Numbers', {'first': 1, 'second': 2})
```

If this suits your needs, you can do

```
>>> en_enum(1)
<Numbers.first: 1>

>>> en_enum(3)
ValueError: 3 is not a valid Numbers
```

not actually membership check, but you don't need any special methods/transformers

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggesion. I think I will stay with `[getattr(an_enum, name) for name in dir(an_enum) if not name.startswith('_')]`, but this way of writing enums is a lot nicer for sure. Also I did not know that you can simply get the enums elements by doing `an_enum(x)`. So thanks!